# Is there a way to flip x and y axis on a pm3d plot

Tags: gnuplot

I have a pm3d plot and I need to flip the x and y axes. My x axis is currently in time (ns) and I need to make that my y axis. With this i would want the old y axis to now be on the x axis.

Comment: I already tried this command>. datafile "file" time 10. I found this command on another post but it didnt work because it says my file cannot be found.

Answer (score 1):

Each plot or splot command that reads a data file accepts a `using` keyword that tells it which columns read the data from.  For a pm3d plot the default is to use the first three columns in the data file as x, y, and z respectively.  This is equivalent to

```
  splot 'datafile' using 1:2:3 with pm3d
```

If you want to swap which is x and which is y for the same data, change this to

```
  splot 'datafile' using 2:1:3 with pm3d
```

Of course you will need to swap the axis labels and ranges also, so that they match the new assignment of data column to plot axis.

Comment: is there a way to do this and keep it as a 2d plot?